# How to use or load flash file exists on different server

Tags: java, flash, xslt, crossdomain.xml

I want to use flash file stored on another server or repository. I am using below code in xsl to add flash file.

https://www.***.com/docs/swf/Spreadsheet.swf

The problem is I am unabele to create swfObject because that flash file is not getting loaded properly on browser. My xslt application is on another server which is trying to access .swf file using above code. I guess there might be domain related issue. I read somewhere about cross domain.xml file.
Is it really required in above scenario? If yes then where to keep that cross domain.xml file? The flash file that I want to access is on another repository which is not on any web server. So can anyone provide me solutions on this?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable like this. **(1)** Explain _"not getting loaded properly"_  it loads something but with errors? Or totally nothing at all? Also show your full swfObject code for our checking. **(2)** At the end you say _"The flash file that I want... which is not on any web server"_ but earlier you said your Flash file is at `https://www.***.com/`. This is confusing since `https://` part tells us it's on a web server. If swf is running from disk (not web) but it tries to communicates with internet it will be blocked as a security issue...

Comment: PS: As a test.. First put your swf file on your `https` web server (so that your shown URL actually exists, check by pasting directly into browser address). Now make a new test html file using a simple `embed` code (no swfObject) like from [**`this example`**](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed) (replace `src="helloworld.swf"` with your `src="https://www.***.com/docs/swf/Spreadsheet.swf"`)... Does `embed` load your swf? Or at least... Does browser load your swf when direct path put into address box?

Comment: PPS: See if you can get a result with a different swf... Right-click & save this [**`SWF file`**](http://swf.wonderfl.net/swf/usercode/d/de/de5b/de5bce1c42bf6875fdb776d56c081ba9a6cb35b2.swf). Save it as `mytest.swf`  put it in same place as `spreadsheet.swf`. Now does either `embed` or even just browser box load the swf when you use : `https://www.***.com/docs/swf/mytest.swf`? **If loaded correctly** you can right-click the app and **it shows Flash version**. If spreadsheet.swf also shows Flash version then it also is loading okay. You don't need a crossdomain.xml